# $this->request->hasArgument('mail') not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm building a typo3 extension. After a form is filled in I want to send an e-mail. In this form the user can fill in it email address. In the backend page I want to grap the mail value but `$this->request->hasArgument('mail')` does replay empty. But when I do a `print_r($_post)` you can see the value is there.

How can I get `$this->request->hasArgument('mail')` working?

Comment: what exactly `print_r($_post)` shows ?

Comment: It shows: ` Array ( [mail] => info@email.nl [lang] => nl [ad_id] => 2 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Extbase extension `$_POST['email']` is not an argument!

Proper `name` attr for the input would be like: `tx_yourext_yourplugin[email]` and only for this methods `hasArgument('mail')` / `getArgument('mail')` will be valid.

You have 2 possibilites:

1. Fix names for the fields to match the above pattern
2. Or use ViewHelper for rendering valid fields (which will do the same as 1), i.e.:

   ```
   <f:form.textfield name="email" id="email" />
   ```